# Returning a C++ reference variable VS returning a variable

Tags: c++

Assume the following function in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int& change(int& a){
   a = 6;
   return a;
}

int main(){
   int a = 5;
   int b = change(a);
   std::cout << b << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Running this will return:

```
6
```

My question is, if I change the return type from `int&` to `int`, compiler won't complain and it will still print 6. So how does retuning a reference work in C++? (comparing it with returning a pointer in C)

Comment: `b` is not a reference, so it doesn't matter whether `change()` returns a reference or not, `b` will make a *copy* of whatever `change()` returns.

Comment: "how does retuning a reference work" is too broad a question.

Answer (score 2):

Reference, like a pointer is implemented by storing the address of an object.

Returning by Value means that it is returning a copy of the old object.

Returning by Reference means that it is returning the address of the old object.

```
#include <iostream>

int& change_ref(int& a) {
    a = 6;
    return a;
}

int change_value(int& a) {
    a = 6;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    change_ref(a) = 7;
    // change_value(a) = 7; compile error
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    int& a1 = change_ref(a); // return reference of a
    // now a1 ref the a
    a1 = 10;
    // print a = 10 and a1 = 10
    std::cout << a << " " << a1 << std::endl;

    int a2 = change_value(a); // return a value of a, so return is 6
    // value of a is 6 and define a new value a2
    a2 = 11;
    // set a2 to 11 and not change a
    // print a = 6, a1=6, a2= 11
    std::cout << a << " " << a1 << " " << a2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `change()` by reference and then updating the actual value of `a` to 6. Since the value of `a` updated to 6, so irrespective of return type `a` will carrying the updated value and always print `6` in the given example.

NOTE: Declared data of `b` is `int`, hence you are not printing any reference.

Comment: so printing a  reference is not like printing a pointer? they are not the same thing?

Comment: @Joe no, they are technically not the same thing (though a reference may be *implemented* using a pointer under the hood)

Comment: @Joe: Declared data of `b` is `int`, hence you are not printing reference.

Comment: changing it to `std::cout << change(a) << std::endl;` still prints 6

Answer (score 1):

You can return by reference as long as it isn't a locally declared variable (as those would be removed from the stack). Returning by reference just means that it is not returning a copy of the object but the actual object.